# grpc++ library is not created by Bazel build. How to make it?

Tags: grpc

I clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc and try to build gRPC++ library with Bazel like this: "bazel build :grpc++"

There are no build errors, but I get: "Target //:grpc++ up-to-date (nothing to build)" and the library artifact is not produced. I tracked it down  to grpc_cc_library(name = "grpc++",  ...) which does not specify any srcs and as the result the header only library produces no binary file.

I searched and could not find any guidance on how grpc++.lib or libgrpc++.so supposed to be built with Bazel. Any help?

Thank you!

Konstantin

Comment: see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md#building-with-bazel-recommended for instructions to build with bazel

Comment: I did just that and it does not produce grpc++ library. I even opened an issue about it: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/28605